# force div to bottom

Tags: html, css

I want the green div to be below the blue div instead of on top of it without changing either of their `position` values and using pure css only.

http://jsfiddle.net/LpjgLydv/40/

Is this possible?

**Assumptions**:

1. I may use inline css only
2. This is for a footer that needs to stay at the bottom regardless of how much content is on the page
3. Any other element on the page besides the footer (and html,head,body) may or may not exist at any given time
4. The footer is nested in `<body>` and cannot be placed anywhere else

Comment: You need absolute position?

Comment: Like this you mean? - http://jsfiddle.net/LpjgLydv/5/

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do and why. Positioning is poor layout method unless used for specific effects.

Comment: If you are using fixed pixel values, this will never work.

Comment: Just search on SO for "sticky footer".

Comment: @Paulie_D: Examples like [this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css) are quite bad since it requires that the css be put in a different element (the wrapper) which may or may not exist on the page at any given time.

Comment: This feels like a **homework** question and I'm not comfortable with doing someone else's homework. No professional web developer would use those constraints.

Comment: @Paulie_D: No worries, please move onto the next question and I will wait for someone with the knowledge and ability to answer. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically I had to add a relative position and a min-height to the html attribute as well as a margin-bottom to the body attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpjgLydv/44/

**html**

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 250px;
}
.box
{
    border: solid 10px blue;
    position: relative;
    height:900px;
    width:380px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.box2
{
    border: solid 10px green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:8px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 380px;
}
```

It now meets the criteria of all of the assumptions in the question.

Comment: Downvoting all answers you get, deleting your own comments, and in the end answering your own questions. You sure got it right how to use SO.

Comment: Thank you, honestly can't take credit for all of it but I do believe that my answer is definitely the best. For anyone else that views this question in future, this would most likely be the quickest solution to their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this without positioning.

```
.inner-box
{
    border: solid 10px blue;
    height:900px;
    width:380px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float:left;

}
.inner-box2
{
    border: solid 10px green;
    float:left;
    bottom:0px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 380px;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: You use float. It is not necessary to have a position in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Add this `bottom:-170px;` to your code (green div). Even if is not a good practice.